# Getting exception while removing multiple slashes from JSON response in C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

This is my respnnse

```
{\"eventResponseList\":[{\"Event_Id\":\"E008\",\"Status_Code\":\"03\",\"Event_time     \":\"\\\/Date(1417001099677)\\\/\"},{\"Event_Id\":\"E002\",\"Status_Code\":\"03\",\"Event_time\":\"\\\/Date(1417001099677)\\\/\"}]}
```

I am using this code to deserialize the response but I am getting exception

```
 if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
   string sanitizedResponseContent = Regex.Replace(response.Content, @"\p{C}+", String.Empty);
   retunResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectEventResponseList>(sanitizedResponseContent);
 }
```

I also used

```
string sanitizedResponseContent = (response.Content).Replace(@"\""", @"""");
```

But every time I am getting this after removing slashes

```
"\"{\"eventResponseList\":[{\"Event_Id\":null,\"Status_Code\":\"02\",\"Event_time\":\"\\\\\\/Date(1417013952712)\\\\\\/\"}]}\""
```

[image: This one is generated error]

Comment: Where are you seeing the slashes? If it is in a debugger then they are not part of the string, the inspector in the debugger is just adding them.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? What is the message?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you're looking at debugger artifacts and misinterpreting what your seeing.

Comment: I am getting this on break point

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach. don't know it'll work for you solution or not. but worth to try.

```
var escape = Regex.Escape(@"\sterte\sfsfs\sssss\ssss");
var replace = Regex.Replace(escape, "\\\\", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DTO's probably should be something similar to this:

```
public class EventResponseList
{
    public string Event_Id { get; set; }
    public string Status_Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime Event_time { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectEventResponseList
{
    public List<EventResponseList> eventResponseList { get; set; }
}
```

If the response string really is in that format then the issue is the whitespaces on the Status_code. They all seem like whitespaces so you could try replacing it with:

```
var json = Regex.Replace(response.Content, @"Event_time[\s]+", "Event_time");
```